# Show previous card on left to right swipe in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am quite new to react native. I want to implement swiping of cards in my app for that I have used [react-native-tinder-swipe-cards](https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards).

Is it possible to show previous card on swiping from left to right. As even if I am decrementing the value for index always the next card is shown which is there at the next index of the array.

What I am trying right now is:

```
 handleYup(card) {
    console.log("yup",card)
    //Alert.alert("Card",card.id+"");
    this.setState({
        cardYup: true
    })

}

handleNope(card) {
    console.log("nope")
    //Alert.alert("Card", card.id + "");
    this.setState({
        cardNope: true
    })

}

cardRemoved(index) {
    if(this.state.cardYup){
        index=index-2;
        this.setState({
            cardYup:false
        })
    }
    else if (this.state.cardNope) {
        //index = index +1
        this.setState({
            cardNope: false
        })
    }
    console.log(`The index is ${index}`);
    Alert.alert("Index", index+"");

    let CARD_REFRESH_LIMIT = 1

    if (this.state.cards.length - index <= CARD_REFRESH_LIMIT) {
        console.log(`There are only ${this.state.cards.length - index - 1} cards left.`);

        if (!this.state.outOfCards) {
            //console.log(`Adding ${cards2.length} more cards`)
            Alert.alert("No Cards","No morecards present")

            this.setState({
                outOfCards: true
            })
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think so library is giving support for this. But you can have your own logic in that library. It has method called `_goToPrevCard` but it is not used anywhere, so you might need to implement it in library itself and than call it from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure some functionality can be added in the existing library but due to time constraints I switched the library from [react-native-tinder-swipe-cards.](https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards) to [react-native-deck-swiper](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper)

And on applying all these props I was able to get the desired functionality

```
            <Swiper
                ref={swiper => {
                    this.swiper = swiper
                }}
                goBackToPreviousCardOnSwipeRight={true}
                showSecondCard={false}
                onSwiped={this.onSwiped}
                onTapCard={this.swipeLeft}
                cards={this.state.cards}
                cardIndex={id}
                renderCard={this.renderCard}
                verticalSwipe={false}
                cardVerticalMargin={5}
                cardHorizontalMargin={5}
                onSwipedAll={this.onSwipedAllCards}
                cardStyle={{height:520}}>
            </Swiper>
```